# Dynamically adding a script tag to page

Tags: javascript, dom, insert

I am trying to add a script to dom using insertBefore.

When running the commands through console, the script is executed as expected, but when the same code piece is run via code, it refuses to execute.

This is the code I am using.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = 'alert("abc");'
el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el.nextSibling)



el.parentNode.replaceChild(s.childNodes[0], el);
el = s.childNodes[0];
for(var i = s.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(s.childNodes[i], el.nextSibling);
```

This is adding the script to the DOM but not executing it.a

Comment: Are you running the code before the DOM is ready?

Comment: try adding the script at the bottom of the document, right before the closing </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate your issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/treeface/8F8bK/

Are you sure your code is being run after the DOM is completely loaded? If you aren't you probably want to run this code like this:

```
window.onload = function() {  
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.text = 'alert("abc");'
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el.nextSibling)
};
```

Comment: Hi yes the code is runnning after the DOM is ready. I am allowing the user to modify his HTML in the browser itself. The input is dynamically added to dom. I'll add some more code examples to make it clearer.